# iOS native app GA tracking (v2) - video and audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I'm trying to track video and audio plays as screen views using the GA iOS SDK v2.  Is this possible?
Normally one would replace the uiviewcontroller reference with GItrackedviewcontroller.  This doesn't seem to be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can manually invoke

```
[tracker sendView:@"My view name"];
```

everytime you open a video or audio stream.
The GAITrackedViewController does nothing other than placing exactly this sendView call in the viewDidAppear (or viewWillAppear, not sure about that).